# How to find Jordan cannonical form for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
   5       &  -1  \\
      4   &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Is the matrix.  I need Jordan canonical form for this matrix.  Also I must find $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J_A$ where $J_A$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$.

The only example I have seen are ones with upper triangular matrix so far.

Firstly I find my characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues, which are $\lambda^2-6\lambda+9$ and $\lambda = 3$ with multiplicity two is my unique eigenvalue.

Nextly I find the nullspace of the $A-3I$ which according to my calculation will be the span of the two standard basis vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.  This is where I become confuse.  What is the next move in the procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately your nullspace calculation is wrong.  You need $(A-3I){\bf v}={\bf0}$, this is not true when $\bf v$ is $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.

Comment: then $v = (0,0)$

Comment: 0 is never an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

When your matrix is not diagonalizeable.

$A[v_1,v_2] = [v_1,v_2] \begin{bmatrix} \lambda &1\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}\\
Av_1 = \lambda v_1\\
A v_2 =\lambda v_2 + v_1$

$(A - 3 I)v_1 = \mathbf 0\\
\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\4&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0\\
(A-\lambda I) v_2 = v_1\\
\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\4&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix} = v_1$